# null pointer exception from my code from the while loop

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I decleared free block like

```
private DoublyLinkedList freeblock = new DoublyLinkedList();
```

and I initialize the freeblock in the constructor.

```
freeblock.add(new DoublyLinkedList.Node(null, null, 0, initBlockSize));
```

inside of one of method of my class, (below is part of my method.)
I get null pointer exception. I think the while loop has a problem. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

symptom: java.lang.NullPointerException
at LinearMemPool.enlarge(LinearMemPool.java:220)

```
private void enlarge(int addSize) {

DoublyLinkedList.Node node = freeblock.head;
    while (node.next != null) { 
            node = node.next;

    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good opportunity to learn how to debug.

Comment: If you still want help, best to post a self-contained compilable example. Also, we should know what DoublyLinkedList is all about. Do you have API docs to refer to? The example should match the compiler output so we can see where line "220" actually is in the code.

Comment: the only thing here that can even possibly throw a nullpointerexception is the "node.next != null" line, because the node variable itself can be null

Comment: also what line is line 220?

Comment: Did you do like a system.out.println(freeblock.head) to see if it null or not?

Comment: Clearly you are trying to perform an operation on a null object and its in line number 220. Just checkout in line 220 which object can be null and why its is not initialized. As Hot Licks said little debug can help.

Comment: line 220 is    
while (node.next != null)

Answer (score 1):

Evidently `freeblock.head` is null. Look what `add` does.

Answer (score 0):

Your `enlarge` method seems a bit dangerous.  Try changing the `null` check to:

```
private void enlarge(int addSize) {
    DoublyLinkedList.Node node = freeblock.head;
    while (node != null) { 
        node = node.next;
    }
}
```

As for the reason why your `head` is `null`, I'd debug the `freeblock.add(...)` method.

Comment: I suggest to simplify it then `DoublyLinkedList.Node node = null;`

Comment: @talex `DoublyLinkedList.Node node = freeblock.head;` is fine.  OP needs a starting `node`.

Comment: I mean as result in you code you get `node==null`. Original code get node equal to last node in list.

Answer (score 0):

First check to see freeblock.head is null because most likely it is:

```
if(node!=null){

   while(node.next!=null){
   ....
}

else{
 System.out.println("Freeblock is null but why.....");

}
```

You probably should do this normally if the freeblock.head can ever be null. And just for cleaning up purposes:

```
void newMethod(Node node, int size){
 if(node!=null)
   enlarge(size);
 else{
   System.out.println("Freeblock is null");
  }
```

}